# Why does using "selector" cause a compiler warning, but @selector(selector) doesn't?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, clang, automatic-ref-counting, selector

I was messing around and just tried implementing a simple non-block / delegate callback function.

```
Class A.m
@implementation noblocks
-(void)logSomethingAndNotify:(id)object andCallSelector:(SEL)selector {

    //some task
    NSLog(@"TRYING THIS OUT");

    //implement callback functionality
    if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(selector)]) {
        [object performSelector:@selector(selector) withObject:object];
    }

}

@end

Class B.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ClassA *noblock = [noblocks new];
    [ClassA logSomethingAndNotify:self andCallSelector:@selector(addSubviewAfterDelay)];
}

-(void)addSubviewAfterDelay {
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self.view addSubview:view];
    });
}
```

In the implementation file of Class A, if I change this statement:

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(selector)]) {            
[object performSelector:@selector(selector) withObject:object];
   }
```

to the selector the way it is represented as a method parameter

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:selector]) {
[object performSelector:selector withObject:object];
}
```

then I get a memory leak warning from the compiler.

I understand that given the dynamic runtime of Objective-C, sending a selectorless message to an unknown object can potentially be problematic - we don't know the return type of the method and can't be sure that we should retain the object returned (if there is one). What I **don't** understand is why using performSelector:@selector(selector) vs just using performSelector:selector **DOESN'T** cause any ARC warning.

This question is NOT a duplicate of others addressing the compiler warning - my question is not about WHY the error is shown so much as why ONE way shows a warning while the OTHER does not.

Comment: Using `@selector(SEL)` isn't valid as the whole point of the `@selector` keyword is to generate/retrieve the `SEL` for the specified selector.  Therefore the first case is invalid.  The reason for the warning is well documented here and elsewhere.

Comment: Invalid how? Both compile and run just fine, it's just that one throws a compiler error and I don't understand why the other one doesn't. It's also not well documented when comparing both cases; I've looked all over. The error message is addressed, not the comparison of cases.

Comment: also, nowhere in my posted code have I written @selector(SEL).

Comment: It's invalid as the argument to `@selector()` should be a method name.  I used the notation `@selector(SEL)` to illustrate the fact that you are calling `@selector()` on a variable of type `SEL`.

Comment: I see. Could you then explain why using @selector(SEL) throws no error while using performSelector:SEL does throw an ARC error? I understand why the entire thing shouldn't be used, it was just a little test.

Comment: No I don't know why.  The warning is valid, however, so needs to be heeded.

Comment: Ok. Well my question was why that was happening - hence, not a duplicate question. Thanks for the input, though. Can you unmark my question as a duplicate so that somebody can possibly answer it?

Comment: I cannot, sorry, only a mod can do that (you can call for mod assistance by flagging the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@selector(selector)` isn't doing what you think it is. :)

Consider:

```
    SEL selector = @selector(hash);
    NSLog(@"%s %s", selector, @selector(selector));
```

This outputs (relying on the fact that an SEL is really a char* as an implementation detail that you should never rely on outside of experiments like this):

```
   asdfasdfa[71281:7385265] hash selector
```

`@selector(selector)` produces a constant value that doesn't trigger the ARC memory warning because the compiler can reason about the code path appropriately.

I.e. consider:

```
    SEL bob = @selector(dobbs);
    NSLog(@"%s %s", bob, @selector(bob));
```

Produces:

```
    asdfasdfa[71313:7394673] hobbs bob
```

The *variable* `bob` refers to the `SEL` `dobbs` whereas `@selector(bob)` produces the `SEL` `bob`.

Comment: To clarify, the reason @selector(selector) doesn't trigger a memory warning is because it checks for the NAME of the selector, whereas SEL causes the compiler to check for a memory address? Might be helpful if you separate the two outputs with a newline character. I tried logging it myself but the compiler was throwing me errors...

Comment: Sort if;  `@selector(selector)` is a static, compile time, expression.  The value it produces is a constant and, thus, the compiler can reason about the method being called.   The moment the SEL argument to `performSelector:` becomes dynamic, the compiler can no longer know that it won't produce a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there is a warning when using `performSelector:` on a dynamic selector value, is that in Cocoa memory management, certain methods are meant to return a retained (+1) instance (i.e. it will be the caller's responsibility to release it). This is by default methods whose names start with `alloc`, `retain`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`. All other methods return a non-retained instance (or retained and autoreleased; anything that doesn't require the caller to release).

`performSelector:`, by its name, is not implied to return a retained instance, and it's not annotated with `ns_returns_retained`. Therefore ARC will consider it to not return a retained instance (which is correct if you use it to perform "normal" methods). But since we don't know what the selector is at compile time, it could be that you are passing one of those selectors that return a retained instance, in which it would be wrong and cause a leak.

In the case where the selector is hard-coded at compile-time, the compiler can check the name at compile time and verify that it is not one of those that return a retained instance.